# Storing Dataframe in ignite cache using cache.put()

Tags: python, ignite

I am using python to create a range query on spatial data and this is my first time dealing with ignite. I have stored my data in a python's Dataframe but I do not know how to put it in the cache. I am only posting here because the majority of search result I find regarding this topic are related to Spark with ignite and are a bit too advance and different from my issue. I only need to store the dataframe into the ignite cache I am not using Spark at all

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('green.txt', sep=",", header=None)
data.columns = ["time", "longitude", "latitude"]
data['Index'] = range(1, len(data) + 1)
data.head()

client = Client()
client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10800)

#Create cache
my_cache = client.create_cache('my cache')

#I need to add my Dataframe values like it is done for Hello World for each row
my_cache.put(1, 'Hello World')
```

Please feel free to close the question if it is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally unaware of Python and dataframes, but if you could save it as CSV (i.e., string), you could easily put this CSV in cache as a value.

Comment: Will I be able to query the data?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "query". You will be able to get that CSV back.